# How in SQL to combine in One Single Condition/Parameter using LIKE Clause and its Wildcard Functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter codes in Sql Server using the **LIKE clause** and its **Wildcard Functions (%, _, ^, [ ] ...)**

My List is As Following:

```
A11111
A11111B
A1112K
A1114AFR
A111GCAS
A111HIV
A71111
AF1111
AQ1111
AT1111
AY1111
AZ11EGWHI
AZ11MEDIA
AZ2111
AZ3111
AZ4111
AZA111
AZB111
AZC111
AZI1111
AZM111
AZN111
AZN1AD
AZO111
AZP111
AZS111
AZU111
AZXT11
AZXT11B
```

And I want to exclude:

1. Anything **beginning with 'AZ'**
2. And anything **beginning exactly with 'A11111'**

I know Sql Code will work like this:

```
SELECT ACNT_CODE
FROM DB
WHERE (DB.ACNT_CODE NOT LIKE 'A[Z]%' AND DB.ACNT_CODE NOT LIKE 'A11111%')
```

But I need the Where clause to be combine in **ONE SINGLE Condition only**
  Like this:

```
SELECT ACNT_CODE
FROM DB
WHERE (DB.ACNT_CODE NOT LIKE 'A[1Z]%')
```

---> However, when I use that, it is still including anything beginning by A1xxx and not exactly A11111%

---> The Challenge is **I CAN ONLY USE (01) One single Condition**, not (02) Two conditions combined by AND. [It's due to an Old program we are using and where I have to abide with :(]

At the end, my result shall be this only:

```
A1112K
A1114AFR
A111GCAS
A111HIV
A71111
AF1111
AQ1111
AT1111
AY1111
```

So, any idea please?

Comment: *"The Challenge is I CAN ONLY USE (01) One single Condition, not (02) Two condition combined by AND"* Why?

Comment: I'm using a very old program. And only 1 single condition using 1 LIKE is accepted. If I add a second LIKE then it uses *OR* but no more *AND* in the conditions

Comment: Why did you remove the sample table data and the expected result? (Note that most people here want formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Sorry, this is my first posting so, I'm still trying to restore it back. I wanted to poste the image, not a disorganized list only

Comment: I've rolled back your edit for you. If you want to add the extra bits you had before, please add them in **addition** to the existing information we have as removing the sample data and expected results was a huge detriment to the question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lamu. I'm not allowed to embed image yet. And now I know how to share the List. (y)

Comment: On a different note, the problem here seems to be your legacy program, not SQL; you might be better asking about that application that you're using and how to have it accept more than one clause in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Don't use images of data at all @TsiriniainaRakotonirina; formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements are far far better.

Comment: It sounds like you might be passing a string into the query, in which case you should be aware of SQL Injection risks.

Comment: Ok, I'm using *Vision Q&A Executive* to design reports. Unfortunately, the only allowed criteria in the program is ONE SINGLE LINE. If I add another line with the same parameter, it changes it to be *OR* and no longer *AND* so  the result is not met.

Comment: Indeed @cloudsafe, that's a risk. But the program accepts SQL format in the _Fitlers_ that's why I need to learn how I retrieve a list and **exclude** from the result items beginning with **AZ** and **A11111** at the same time.

Comment: @TsiriniainaRakotonirina Are you also restricted to using LIKE? Could you use IN or rewrite the statement completely?

Comment: @cloudsafe, unfortunately, what the program recognizes are **[NOT] LIKE**, **[NOT] BETWEEN**, **EQUAL (=)**, **DIFFERENT (<>)**, **LESSER/GREATE/EQUAL (>, >=, <, <=)**. And that's it. That's why I'm completely stuck

Comment: So, I was thinking **LIKE** is the most flexible among them and I can use **_, [ ], ^, %** in the Parameters of the program. But I can't find a way to set 2 parameters in one time.

Comment: What happens if you try and do your own SQL injection? Use NOT LIKE and pass "A[Z]%' AND DB.ACNT_CODE NOT LIKE 'A11111%" as your value string (not including the double quotes). If it handles SQL injection properly it won't work. If it does work, then ouch - that's a massive security risk.

Comment: @DancingFool: No, it doesn't work.
I tried is and go this:
`AND RTRIM(DB.ACCNT_CODE) LIKE N''' AND DB.ACNT_CODE NOT LIKE N''A11111%'''`

---> Too much apostrophies and doesn't work

Comment: Why don't you simply use left function if your result set has specific filters

Comment: Since no one (apparently) knows the abilities of your program, you need to think outside the box. If you can write the actual "select" portion of the query, you can use a CTE to filter by one condition and select from that cte to filter by the 2nd condition. A stored procedure is another path. Use of INTERSECT perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much for all your propositions and answers, which I appreciate. But since my need is for a **SINGLE CONDITION WITH LIKE**, so if the solution is more than one line, then it won't work with the software.

However, I found a work around to get it to meet what I want in one line, but I had to add another column with the Current List:

```
- ACNT_CODE -  - TYPE -
A11111         ACHIGH01
A11111B       ACHIGH01
A1112K        ACOTHER01
A1114AFR      ACOTHER01
A111GCAS      ACOTHER01
A111HIV       ACOTHER01
A71111        ACOTHER01
AF1111        ACOTHER01
AQ1111        ACOTHER01
AT1111        ACOTHER01
AY1111        ACOTHER01
AZ11EGWHI     ACLOWER01
AZ11MEDIA     ACLOWER01
AZ2111        ACLOWER01
AZ3111        ACLOWER01
AZ4111        ACLOWER01
AZA111        ACLOWER01
AZB111        ACLOWER01
AZC111        ACLOWER01
AZI1111       ACLOWER01
AZM111        ACLOWER01
AZN111        ACLOWER01
AZN1AD        ACLOWER01
AZO111        ACLOWER01
AZP111        ACLOWER01
AZS111        ACLOWER01
AZU111        ACLOWER01
AZXT11        ACLOWER01
AZXT11B       ACLOWER01
```

Then in my SQL, I use the same **LIKE with SINGLE CONDITION** as follows:

```
SELECT ACNT_CODE
FROM DB
WHERE (DB.TYPE NOT LIKE 'AC[HL]%') --Excluse ACHIGH01 & ACLOWER01
```

Or a simpler one:

```
SELECT ACNT_CODE
FROM DB
WHERE (DB.TYPE LIKE 'AC[O]%') --Include only ACOTHER01
```

It's the same as `WHERE (DB.TYPE LIKE 'AC[ˆHL]%') --Excluse ACHIGH01 & ACLOWER01`

Definitely, at the end, the result is this:

```
A1112K
A1114AFR
A111GCAS
A111HIV
A71111
AF1111
AQ1111
AT1111
AY1111
```

However, for the purpose of SQL search and learning, I leave this question always open if someone else find a better one without the other column.

Answer (score 2):

You can invert the logic to get what *is* allowed.  I believe this is the correct logic:

```
WHERE DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE '[^A]%' OR
      DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A[^Z1]%' OR
      DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A1[^1]%' OR
      DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A11[^1]%' OR
      DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A111[^1]%' OR
      DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A1111[^1]%'
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for the attempt.
But the first filter reject everything the `'[^A]%'` and the 2nd filter rejects even parts of the wanted results which begins with **A1** but is not exactly **A11111** or **A11111B**

Comment: @Tsiriniaina . . . These are connect by `OR`.  The first returns everything that doesn't begin with an A -- all those seem acceptable.  The second, any string that doesn't start with AZ or A1 -- all those are acceptable.  And so on.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, I'm using Vision Q&A Executive to design reports. Unfortunately, the only allowed criteria in the program is ONE SINGLE LINE. If I add another line with the same parameter, it changes it to be OR and no longer AND so the result is not met

So use OR then.

```
SELECT ACNT_CODE
FROM DB
WHERE DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE '[B-Z]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE '[0-9]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A[A-Y]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A0%''
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A10%''
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A1[2-9]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A110%''
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A111[2-9]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A1110%''
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A1111[2-9]%'
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A11110%''
OR    DB.ACNT_CODE LIKE 'A11111[2-9]%'
```

Comment: If the requirement is not about **SINGLE CONDITION** then I would have selected yours.
However, those Account Codes are different from an Organization to another Oganization, which means that I cannot hardcode the LIKE but has to get it **simple**, **short** but **dynamic**. That's why I needed a SINGLE Condition, to avoid me to have too difficult filters not understandable by the End users. But thanks @JohnWu for your solution.